# Adding unusual background to transparent image

Tags: html, css, image, background

```css
.half-half-image-text {
  padding: 70px 0px;
}
.half-half-image-text h1 {
  color: #800000;
}
.half-half-image-text .content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 35px 0px;
}
.half-half-image-text .content p {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.half-half-image-text .img {
  min-height: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-half-image-text">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Our Mission</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="content">
        <p>At Fluid Automotive, our purpose is to make automotive parts easily accessible for everyone. Working with our partner brands, we aim to retail the highest quality parts, whilst maintaining a high level of customer satisfaction.</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="img" style="background: url('https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Happy-Person-Free-Download-PNG.png')no-repeat center;width:40%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Hi What am I trying to achieve is depicted on the screen attached. I am trying to apply to a transparent image a background like this(purple in this example) a shape can be similar.

What am I looking for is a source of knowledge (links ets) for that kind of problem and would very much appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: Please include any applicable HTML & CSS.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: @Kameron inserted some code, could be possible to add that effect to the guy on image?